# Scope of objects in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I am new to C# and trying to understand lambda expressions along with delegates. This is the code I am running:

```
delegate bool D1();
delegate bool D2(int i);

namespace Console
{
    class Program
    {
        D1 d1;
        D2 d2;

        public void testMethod(int input)
        {
            int j = 0;
            d1 = () => { j = 10; return j < input; };
            d2 = (x) => { return x == j; };
            System.Console.WriteLine("j = {0}", j);

            bool res = d1();
            System.Console.WriteLine("res={0}, j ={1}", res, j);

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.testMethod(10);
            System.Console.WriteLine(p.d2(10));
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is the invocation of `d2` prints `true`. When `d2`  was constructed value of `j` was `0`. It was changed only after `d1` was invoked later in the `testMethod`. So how it is printing `True` ? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d1` and `d2` both refer to the same instance of `j`. When you set `j` by calling `d1` you're also altering the value of the variable that `d2` can see.

If you want them do have different instance of `j` you'll need to scope the variable:

```
{
  int j = 0;
  d1 = () => { j = 10; return j < input; };
}

{
  int j = 0;
  d2 = (x) => { return x == j; };
}
```

However, if you're going to do this then you might as well have two different variables, say `j1` and `j2` instead. This will be more readable.

Comment: thanks..is there any way I can control this so that `d1` & `d2` will get separate instances of `j`?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a delegate, any variable outside its scope that it uses is captured. In this case, the delegates assigned to `d1` and `d2` both capture the variable `j` declared inside `testMethod()`; they don't create copies of `j`, they capture the actual variable. In this sense, during the lifetime of `d1` and `d2`, `j` behaves inside them as if it was a global variable (though there is no such thing as a global variable in C#, of course).

If you want those methods to get separate instances of `j`, you would need to provide each method with a copy of `j` instead of just using it. For instance:

```
public void testMethod(int input)
{
    int j = 0;
    int k = j;
    d1 = () => { j = 10; return j < input; };
    d2 = (x) => { return x == k; };
    System.Console.WriteLine("j = {0}", j);

    bool res = d1();
    System.Console.WriteLine("res={0}, j ={1}", res, j);

}
```